# Is there the same syntax in Julia look like syntax: print(f"{ }") in Python?

Tags: syntax, julia

In Python, we have the syntax:

```python
print(f"This is a number {1}")
```

In Julia, is there the similar syntax or similar method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation is done with `$(...)` in Julia, see the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#string-interpolation). Example:

```
julia> x = 1; y = "world";

julia> str = "x is $(x) and y is $(y)"
"x is 1 and y is world"
```

Comment: Thank you. In Python, we also have syntax: `print(f"save two digits {2.34444: .2f}")`. So we can print a number with two digits. I am reading the document you shared, but I don't find the same method to do that. So, Could we also do that in Julia?

Comment: You have to reach out for a package, like `Printf`, in this case. And do `@printf "save two digits %.2f" 2.34444` to get the same output as Python's. IMO, these are the type of things that are intuitive in Python, yet more involved in Julia.